# I can not access all the tables in my sql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

Please can somebody help me with this problem.
I have a Form in VBA and from this from I want to run some SQL queries and retrieve the data from my database and then place the result in a Text box in the Form(GUI)

I have about 20 tables in my Database but surprisingly to me I am only able to access the first table (InventoryCompleteList).
Every attempt to access another table returns an error saying for example (Invalidobject name 'functionalTestResults') whereas when I run the query for (inventoryCompleteList), it seems to be working. Note functionalTestResults and inventoryCompleteList are both tables in my sql server 
Please can anyone help me figure out what the problem might be. 
Below is the view of my DB

```
`Private Sub ENTER_Click()
 Dim cn As Object
 Dim rs As Object
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strCon As String
 Dim strSQL, strInput As String

 strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security  
 Info=True;Initial Catalog=KBOW;Data Source=10.23.30.8\KBOW;Use Procedure 
 for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation 
 ID=ULWW101;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when   
 possible=False;"


 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 cn.Open strCon



 strSQL = "SELECT Date,Location FROM functionalTestResults;"

 'Added the following four lines
 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
 rs.ActiveConnection = cn
 rs.Open strSQL
 Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
 Result.Text = "CopyFromRecordset rs"
 'removed
 'cn.Execute strSQL


 rs.Close
 cn.Close
 Set cn = Nothing

 End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be granted "Select" on those tables, as it seems you currently do not have this permission.

Speak with your dba about being granted access to this table.

Comment: Thanks very much Philip. The issue is if I go to " Add data-External source-SQL Server on the Excel workbook and I give in the Server name and the Database name, I am able to access each of the table and able to import them one table at a time. So I was thinking that I already have access to the database. I would have done this with Excel macro but I was also forced to select only one table at a time and I could  not have chance to only have all the connection open without selecting a particular table.